# A question about a succession study by Chapin et al. (1994)

Tags: ecology, community-ecology

The succession study in Glacier Bay, Alaska ([Chapin et al., 1994](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.2307/2937039/full)) is an example that is used in almost all introductory texts on ecological succession. In the study, the effect of each succession stage on the germination and development of spruce seedling was examined, and complex results were found (see Figure 4b in [here](http://www.nature.com/scitable/knowledge/library/succession-a-closer-look-13256638)). For example, In *Dryas* stage (one of successional stages), spruce seedlings had weak germination and survival rates due to increase in seed predators. Likewise, the results show the effect of each successional stage on the various attributes of seedling germination and survival.

My question here is what is the control/reference of this study? For example, *Dryas* stage decreased the survival of seedlings compared to what condition? The results show "increase" and "decrease", but the reference is not clear. Is the control same for all successional stages?